# Xcode 15.2 Linker command failed with exit code 1 for the Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform, mobile-development

I'm trying to build a Kotlin multiplatform application. In Android Studio, I created a Kotlin multiplatform library and published it to a local Maven repository to use it in Android. For iOS, I created a Swift package and uploaded the package to a github repository. Then, in the iOS app, I added it as a package dependency. Everything worked fine until I updated Xcode to version 15.2. After the update, when I run the project, it shows the error "unidentified symbols" and "linker command failed with exit code 1". I tried running the project on Xcode version 15.1, and the project ran successfully. The issue is with version 15.2.

I had tried to clean and rebuild the project, delete derived data, and clean the simulator; Xcode was uninstalled and reinstalled. I created a new Swift package from the Kotlin Multiplatform Library project and tried adding it as a package dependency by putting it in another github repository. I tried changing project settings.

Below added the shared build.gradle.kts file
import java.util.Properties

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)

    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinxSerialization)
    id("maven-publish")
    alias(libs.plugins.swiftPackageBuilder)
}

group = "com.example.kmmmovies"
version = "0.0.1"

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    kotlin.applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate()

    androidTarget {
        publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "movies"
        }
    }

    multiplatformSwiftPackage {
        swiftToolsVersion("5.3")
        targetPlatforms {
            iOS { v("13") }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                //put your multiplatform dependencies here
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.content.negotiation)
                implementation(libs.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json)

                //Use api so that the android app can use it as well
                api(libs.koin.core)
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.android)

                api(libs.koin.android)
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.kmmmovies"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
}
```

Kotlin version 1.9.21

Swift package is created by using plugin com.chromaticnoise.multiplatform-swiftpackage:2.0.3"

I had selected Regular framework while creating project

The error :

ld: warning: ignoring file '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Movie-ckfahhxbqvyylzeohznjkkovjxjc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/movies.framework/movies': found architecture 'x86_64', required architecture 'arm64'
ld: Undefined symbols:

*OBJC_CLASS*$_MoviesGetMoviesUseCase, referenced from:
in HomeViewModel.o

*OBJC_CLASS*$_MoviesKoinHelperKt, referenced from:
in MovieApp.o

*OBJC_CLASS*$_MoviesMovie, referenced from:
in HomeScreen.o

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please add more detail. What Kotlin version, how are you creating the SPM package and uploading, more of the error, what is your framework build config from Gradle. static/dynamic, that kind of thing. Xcode should have more info as well, possibly the symbols that aren't identified. I would also assume 15.2 is rather new, and KMP may not officially support that (although it'll probably work).

Comment: The build gradle file, Kotlin version, method of creating a Swift package, and error were updated in the question.